# jQuery not working after host change

Tags: jquery

I recently changed my host and a page that was previously working no longer works. I think it might be the jQuery that it broken but I can't be sure and I'm not sure what code you need to see in order to determine what the issue is as people have had an issue with me posting a lot of code in the past. Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: Look in your developer's console and see if any jQuery scripts are giving you a 404 error, or if you have any unusual errors in general.

Comment: There are no errors in the console. It's not returning anything. Some of the jQuery is working but parts of it no longer work

Comment: You could take a local version for your jquery and test.

Comment: you have jQuery from CDN or as file stored within your web directory?, post the link of your site

Comment: jQuery is hosted at Google which I've been using before and never had a problem

Comment: My car is broken. I won't show you the car, tell you anything about it, where it is, or any other detail. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is run client side. As long as all the assets are loading properly the host would make very little difference.

Check your console for anything not loading properly, that's the first step.

After that check any server side scripts that your jQuery might be interacting with. It's far more likely that some host difference is affecting a server side script and something going wrong with that script is then affecting the jQuery.

Those sort of vague things are about all we can tell you, because **"*not working*" is not a description of a problem.**

Without telling us what is expected, what actually is happening, and in general *describing the problem* there isn't much we can tell you.